# Differentiability of a Dirichlet Function Modified with $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

I am quite stumped on a homework question for my real analysis course. The question is as follows:

Prove that $g(x)=\begin{cases} 
x^2 & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 & x\not\in \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{cases}$ **is** differentiable at $c = 0$.

Here is my work so far:

The derivative of $g(x)$ at $c=0$ exists if $\lim_{x\to0^{-}} \frac {g(x)-g(0)} {x-0} = \lim_{x\to0^{+}} \frac {g(x)-g(0)} {x-0}$.

By $0\in \mathbb{Q}$
$$
\lim_{x\to0^{-}} \frac {g(x)-g(0)} {x-0} = \lim_{x\to0^{-}} \frac {g(x)} {x} =
\frac {\lim_{x\to0^-}g(x) } {\lim_{x\to0^{-}}x}
$$

Here is where I am confused. I don't see how to deal with the indeterminant form above. We are not allowed to use L'Hopital's rule, as we only proved it last lecture and it was not in the material for this section. I imagine we would use the density of $\mathbb{R}$ and the sequence convergence criterion, as we did with our original section on pathological functions, but I'm not even sure how to start.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a proof by definition, but with a new definition of differentiability other than yours.

> $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c\in(a,b)$ if the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists.

This somehow is equivalent to your definition. Now, as you mentioned, the limit of the difference quotient is $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{g(x)}{x}$$
So for any $\epsilon>0$, we can pick $\delta=\epsilon$ such that for any $x$ with $|x|<\delta$, if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then we have $$\left|\dfrac{g(x)}{x}\right|=\left|\dfrac{x^2}{x}\right|=|x|<\delta=\epsilon$$
If $x\in\mathbb{I}:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, then we have
$$\left|\dfrac{g(x)}{x}\right|=0<\epsilon$$
So the limit exists and thus we get $g$ is differentiable.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I would upvote if I could but as I am new it won't let me.

Answer (score 1):

$$0<\frac{|g(x)|}{|x|} \leq |x|$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} 0 \leq \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{|g(x)|}{|x|} \leq \lim_{x \to 0} |x| \implies \lim_{x \to 0} |\frac{g(x)}{x}| = 0 \iff \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{x} = 0$$